# Entropy of sum of random variables

Tags: probability, entropy

Let $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$ by random variables which take the values $0$ or $1$ with $P(x_i = 1)  = p_i$ and $P(x_i = 0) = 1-p_i$, where $0 \leq p_i \leq 1$ for $i=1,2,\dots, n$.   Let $$X= \sum_{i=1}^n x_i.$$

> Is it true that the entropy of $X$ is maximal when $p_i = 1/2$ for
>   $i=1,2,\dots, n$?

Comment: True but not very easy http://statweb.stanford.edu/~ckirby/techreports/NSF/OLK%20NSF%20131.pdf

Comment: @leonbloy Thanks for the reference. I will leave the question open in case anyone has a nice way of explaining it an answer here.